# Course of actions after finding security flaw

Tags: disclosure

I've found what I believe is a significant security flaw on quite a big platform. It can be exploited to obtain on the orders of millions of email addresses with some additional data. They're big enough in that they have set up a customer support system, which is causing me great problems in getting in touch with the right person.

Is there a good course of action I can take in such circumstances?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check `whois` - there may be usable contact information there.

you could try emailing postmaster@theirdomain - that's supposed to connect to a human admin of some type.

contact the cyber emergency response team. aka CERT, they may have a better means of contact. EG: www.us-cert.gov